# Syntax error happen when following intern-tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, intern

New to intern.js, following the tutorial (https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial), stuck after typing the followings in bash.

node ./node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=tests/intern

and this shows up:

> Defaulting to "console" reporter
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>       at Function.vm.runInThisContext (/Users/[username]/Dropbox/internjs/intern-tutorial/node_modules/intern/node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:163:16)
>       at /Users/uuuh/Dropbox/internjs/intern-tutorial/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:760:8
>       at fs.js:266:14
>       at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

Would greatly appreciate if any hint/direction someone can point me to.

Comment: If you cut-and-pasted the code from a web site, then there's a good chance that there is one or more hidden Unicode special characters in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript code that you are attempting to load contains syntax errors. Check your JavaScript files using a code linter like jshint for syntax errors and fix them.

Comment: Thanks, I nuked the folder and re-did the tutorial. Seems working now.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting exactly the same error. nuking and reinstalling hasn't fixed it. jshint shows nothing unusual.

The problem was that when I edited the intern.js config file, I deleted one of the closing apostrophes (or rather vi did).

So... double check your edit of intern.js

Comment: Thanks, this is likely the case. However I don't have the original anymore.